# C# String match (result) from .txt file

Tags: c#, file, foreach, match, contains

**TEXT.txt**:

```
who     
when   
what   
how
```

**Example.cs**:

```
String example = "what is the time" ;

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\TEXT.txt"))
{
    if (example.Contains(line))
    {
        Messagebox.Show("True, the match is 'what'");
    }
}
```

I've made a text file, `TEXT.txt`, and a piece of code that checks if any of the lines in the text file match something in the example string. **How do I see what the actual match is?** In this case it would be `what`.

Comment: What about Messagebox.Show(line); ?

Comment: In your case 'what' is the line variable.

Comment: You should cast the line and your 'search string' to 'ToLowerInvariant()' else 'what' will not match 'What' and vice versa.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Yes thanks, but in this case I'm using an grammar so as long as I type the grammar in lower I thinks i'm gonna be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
 Messagebox.Show("True, the match is '" + line + "'");
```

Answer (score 5):

Is the "actual match" not just the variable *line*?
Hence:

```
Messagebox.Show(string.Format("True, the match is '{0}'", line));
```